# IntelliJ Ultimate - SpringBoot Run Configuration How To Set Maven Profile (NOT Spring Profile)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently on `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)`. In my project, there's a combination of Maven Profiles & Spring Profiles.

There's two maven profiles, **dev** and **prod** as you can see below where prod is the default. We have some dependencies we only want if we're running the dev profile.

```xml
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>dev</name>
                </property>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
                    <version>${springdoc-openapi.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>prod</name>
                </property>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to set the profile using the IntelliJ Run Configuration that the Ultimate edition has for Spring Boot. I only see a way to set the **spring profile** *not* the **maven profile**. I do not see anything under Modify Options in the Run Configuration window to help either.

I know I can instead setup a Run Configuration for Maven with `mvn spring-boot:run -Pdev` but wasn't sure if there's another way?

Comment: You can set the spring profile in your run configuration.... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent

Comment: @khmarbaise I am asking about setting the Maven Profile not a Spring Profile from the Run Configuration using "Spring Boot" as the run config option.

Answer (score 1):

IDEA manages Maven profiles via the Maven Tool Window (View -> Tool Windows -> Maven).
So in order to apply a Maven Profile to your Project you would have to do the following:

1. Activate the desired Profile via the Tool Window. (see [IDEA Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-profiles.html#activate_maven_profiles))
2. Click "Reload All Maven Projects" button in the Tool Window so it applies the changes.
3. Run your Spring Boot Configuration as normal and it should pick up
   Maven Profile you've selected.

Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: So I would prefer if I didn't have to do that so I can have different Run Configurations in IntelliJ for the maven profiles of Dev and Prod for example instead of needing to remember to change it via the Maven Tool Window

Comment: Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any other way to do that.
There is a YouTrack Issue you can upvote to raise the priority of implementing this functionality:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87143